# Javascript - this vs window

Tags: javascript, syntax

If you can, if the code is not invoked in a function, should you use this instead of window?

```
this.addEventListener(...);

vs

window.addEventListener(...);
```

this is 2 chars shorter, is it better to use if you can?

Comment: this doesnt mean to be a window all the time ..the value of this depends on how the function is invoked

Comment: @AvinashBabu I said if I can, of course inside a function it wouldn't work.

Comment: Using `this` will be confusing to readers of the application. While it does refer to the window in global contexts, it's very unusual to depend on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend avoid 'this' unless its explicitly specified via `call`, `apply`, or `bind`. That way there's never any question about what `this` refers to. And I'm also fond of always explicitly declaring access to a global object:

```
(function(global, document, undefined){
    global.myGlobalVar = 'foo';
})(window, document);
```

This way it is always clear when I'm doing anything global, the code can be more easily ported to a non-browser environment like `node.js`, undefined will always be undefined, etc.

If you don't make your global access explicit and have to try to find it later, you **will** regret it. If you're registering an event handler globally (probably not the best idea) you definitely want to make note of it.

EDIT: Should probably mention that in strict mode `this` is undefined in the global scope.

Comment: This is probably the answer Murplyx is looking for.  It's more about clarity than saving on characters, and `this`' ambiguity will obscure the purpose of your code.

Answer (score 1):

`this` and `window` are not the same thing.  Depending on context, `this` can refer to any number of elements, while window always means window.

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this for more info

Answer (score 0):

What ever arguments you are looking for; typing two characters more or less is not it.

this and window are different things.
'window' is the whole web page.
'this' depends on the function you are in.

Answer (score 0):

In the environment of a web browser, `this`refers to the Window object, if no other context is given.
Using `Window` would make it less dubious, so I would go with `Window` if necessary.

Note that it is always good practice to add eventlisteners to the smallest possible context for performance reasons.
If only a part of the DOM needs to listen for events, there is no need to add an eventlistener in the browser global scope.

Aside from an event listener on the body element for removing eg. popup windows, I never added eventlisteners to the Window object before.

Answer (score 0):

This refers to the parent of whatever code block you're currently inside.  If the code is inside a click event, 'this' refers to the control that invoked the event.  If the code is run on page load, 'this' refers to the browser window.  Using 'window' makes it more apparent to what you're referring and makes the code more readable.